# How does one determine $n$-spheres of curvature?

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry

I am aware of circles of curvature and I am simply wondering to what extent does this generalize to $n$-dimensions.  Specifically, if some surface in $n$-dimensional space is represented parametricaly, how does one determine the $n$-sphere of curvature at any given point?

Comment: The 3-sphere of curvature is also called an [osculating sphere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OsculatingSphere.html).

Comment: But note that this is a sphere in contact with a curve, not with a two-dimensional surface. In general, a (hyper)surface doesn't have a sphere of curvature but a (hyper)ellipsoid of curvature, since it can have different curvature in different directions. By the way, if a (hyper)surface in $n$-dimensional space had a sphere of curvature, it would be an $(n-1)$-sphere, not an $n$-sphere.

Comment: Space curves do have osculating spheres and osculating circles (the circle formed by the intersection of the osculating sphere and osculating plane).